# Call command of web service from command line of Python

Tags: python, urllib

I do the following Python commands:

```
import urllib

data = urllib.urlencode({"contains":"my_function"})

u = urllib.urlopen("http://myservername:1000/myfolder/?%s" % data)

u.read()
```

Then I get from that read command a lot of lines with HTML tags and one of the strings is of my interest. It looks like this:

...... onClick='doCommand("my_function","51267", $("ttt27222").value); $("ttt27222").value="";'  >Apply

This is what I want to do from command line of Python using urllib.
Please let me know how to build urllib statement in order to call this my_function function passing it two parameters: 51267 and soem number for value.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`doCommand()` seems like a javascript function. `urllib` doesn't execute javascript. You could use [selenium webdriver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/), [ghost.py](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/) to emulate web browser (to execute javascript in the context of the web page).